# Netbeans IDE - I can't include MySQL connector into the final jar

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jar, mysql-connector

I have a big problem including the MySQL connector into the final jar of my project.

No problem in running and debugging (always in Netbeans IDE) the project because the MySQL Connector is detected. Normally, I add it through the "Add Jar/Folder" function in the folder "libraries" in my project, but when I use the "Clean and Build" function Netbeans doesn't include it in the final jar.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had already downloaded the Connector software, and it works when I run and debug the project on Netbeans. Asking Netbeans IDE to create the jar of my project it doesn't include the MySQL Connector. Why?